# Facebook SDK with Typescript

Tags: typescript, fbsdk

I found this Project on github: 
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fbsdk/fbsdk.d.ts

But when I want to export this I get a Typescript error "this is not a module" by using this call:

```
export { fbsdk } from '../controllers/fbsdk';
```

File name is "fbsdk.d.ts"

And on the bottom of the file it should be declared as module:

```
declare module "FB" {
    export = FB;
}

declare namespace FB {
    export interface LoginStatusResponse {
        authResponse?: AuthResponse;
        status: LoginStatus;
    }
}

declare var FB : FBSDK;
```

Comment: `FBSDK` is not a module but an interface. What about this `export { fb } from '../controllers/fbsdk';`?

Comment: still the same error other suggestions?

Comment: what about this `export * as FB from "FB";`